Prove that the segment $BE$ intersects the common point of two circles
The isosceles triangle $ABC$ is inscribed in the circle $C_1$ (the big one). Tracing the $r$ line from $A$, the point $D$ is the intersection of $r$ with $C_1$. Drawing a new circle $C_2$ (the small one) with radius $CD$, the point $E$ is the intersection of $r$ and $C_2$.
The original problem is about proving that $ABE$ is an isosceles triangle too, and there are various ways to do that e.g. the one described here.
But I would like to demonstrate first that the segment $BE$ intersects the common point of the two circles (from that is very easy to prove the original statement).
Is there any way to do that?


Let $C \neq X = C_1 \cap C_2$. Note that
$$\begin{align} \angle BXC &= 180^\circ -\angle BAC
\\ &= 180^\circ -\angle ACB \\
&= 180^\circ - \angle ADB \\
&= \angle BDE
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align} 2(\angle BXC+CXE) &= \angle BXC+\angle BXC + 2\angle CXE \\
&= \angle BDC+\angle BDE + \angle CDE \\
&= 360^\circ
\end{align}$$
which implies $B,X,E$ are collinear. $\blacksquare$

Let's mark the point of intersection of two circles as $P$. We know that $DC = DP$, as radiuses of $C_{2}$. Now let $E'$ be the point of intersection of $BP$ and $AD$. We want to prove that $E' = E$. $∠CBD = ∠DBP$, because $DC = DP$ (this means that $◡DC = ◡DP$, and so the angles are equal, too); $∠BAD = ∠DPE'$, because $ABPD$ is inscribed in $C_1$. Let $∠CBD = ∠DBP = a$, $∠DPE' = ∠BAD = ∠BCD = x$; $∠BAC = ∠BCA = x + a$ (because the triangle is isosceles),  $∠ACD = 2x + a$, $∠ABD = 180° - 2x - a$, $∠ABP = ∠ABD + ∠DBP = 180° - 2x - a + a = 180° - 2x$, $∠ADP = 2x$. This is an exterior angle for $ΔDPE: 2x = x + ∠DE'P$. This means that $∠DE'P = x = ∠DPE'$, and by this we can conclude that $DP = DE'$, or that E' lies on $C_2$. But $E'$ also lies on AD, so it is the intersection of $AD$ and $C_2$, and because of this $E' = E$. Finally, $BE' = BE$ passes through $P$, which is the intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$. Q.E.D.

